# Weird characters on WiFi Console

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-uno-wifi

> Device : Arduino **UNO WiFi Developer Edition**.
>
> IDE: Arduino IDE 1.8.2
>
> OS : Windows 7 64 bit

I have an issue with my Arduino device where it simply stops printing to serial and the Wifi console output is just garbage text/weird characters. Here example codes of it working and when it's not working:

**WORKING**

```cpp
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Testing...");
  delay(5000);
}
```

**NOT WORKING**

```cpp
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ciao.begin();
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Testing...");
  delay(5000);
}
```

**What I have tried:**

- Reset
- Firmware Update
- Unplug/Replug device
- Change port
- Change board to NodeMCU or ESP8266
- Download and re-install IDE
- Reboot Laptop
- Uninstall & re-install device drivers
- Try previous Arduino Uno Wifi Dev Ed library
- Restart/Reset WiFi

**Garbage text WiFi console:**

[image: garbage text wificonsole]

Any suggestions, ideas and solutions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting [connectivity] parameters. Click on [CONNECTIVITY], then fill in:
Server port: 1883
Client ID: arduino
Client Timeout: 2

### Keep Alive: 60

Topic: arduino
[v] ENABLE SLIP...

Click on both [UPDATE] buttons, and ensure that parameters are registered.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysu8S.jpg)